# Recover a minecraft seed

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The world I've been playing crashed recently and took the level.dat with it, so I've recreated it, however I have no idea what my seed used to be, and I really don't want to end up with another corrupted game world from exploring with the wrong seed.

How can I recover the seed which was used to generate my world?

Comment: Just to get in front of the widely circulated and completely wrong answer, using '0' as the seed does not work.

Comment: This thread may contain answers: http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/seeds/313689-how-do-i-find-out-my-multiplayer-seed (I gave up, reading forums is like accelerated brain cancer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done using a third party tool, [**NBTExplorer**](https://github.com/jaquadro/NBTExplorer) which reads the data files used by Minecraft:

1. Open the save folder for the world, e.g. `.minecraft\saves\MyWorld`
2. Find the file called `level.dat_mcr` and copy it out of the save folder
3. Rename the file to `level.dat`
4. Open it with NBTExplorer
5. Expand the 'Data' tab by clicking on the `[+]` button next to it.
6. Double click on the `RandomSeed` key, and you'll get a popup window containing the original seed for the level, like this:

   [image]
7. Copy this value into the same place in the new **`level.dat`** for your save file, then save and close it.

Your new level.dat file will then have the same seed as the old one.