# How can i lock the same custom map in every new single world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-mods

So, to be more precise, I want to create something like this:

-I want to enter the minecraft lobby and when I press the singleplayer and create a new world, the present map would be the same over and over like modpack such as crashlanding or skyblock.

I notice was well, if I create a chunk(s) in MCedit, and remove all the other and save the map, when I enter the save file, the game would keep the chunk i design but fill the void ones with random blocks, I wonder how  can I recreate a world starting in the same spot over and over again but having certain chuncks every time I start a game and let MC fill the empty ones, adding the same custom base every time but give the random terrain of the empty chunks recreated by MC.

I would be grateful if I could have some hints/help on what to do on config files or mods that can make what I want!

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the [world seed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22474/how-do-level-seeds-work). In simple terms, the seed is a number that tells the game how to generate the terrain.

You have 2 options to create a world with a particular seed:

1. Find the seed of the map you want to recreate (press F3 for debug information in-game, or use various tools to [recover the seed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/186721/recover-a-minecraft-seed)). Create a new world, and enter this seed under "More World Options"
2. Select a world from the single-player menu and click "Re-Create" to automatically make a new world with the same seed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control world generation mechanics you need to write your own mod that adds your preference and logic to a "world type" and then the world has to be generated using it.

For further information about how others have done this you can look at:

- [Underground BiomeConstructs](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1293503-1-7-2-underground-biomes-constructs)
- [Highlands](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/2104582-forge-highlands-2-2-1-updated-june-10)
- [BWG4](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1281910-better-world-generation-4-v1-2-1)
- [Enhanced Biomes](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1294692-enhanced-biomes-pre-2-4a-nearly-100-new-biomes-15)
- [Biomes O Plenty](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1286162-biomes-o-plenty-over-75-new-biomes-plants-and-more)
- And more, I'm sure you can find them.

If you want to see a youtube video containing examples of these world generation mods (which is also where I found the above list) you can visit:

[Minecraft - Top 5 World Generation Mods (1.7.10) - 2014](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gt5mpKtb2Ck)