# Minecraft Beta 1.7.3 seed viewer

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Simply put, how can I map a specific seed in minecraft easily - I have found a few seed viewers but they are all for MC1.8, and I have also looked around and discovered a program called MCEdit, but they no longer distribute the 1.0 release and I get 404'd. Does anyone know of a good beta 1.7.3 seed viewer?

Comment: Questions that directly ask for recommendations to software are off-topic on this site.  In the future, try simply asking "How can I obtain the seed used for a minecraft map?". That question has been answered (see below):

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recover a minecraft seed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/186721/recover-a-minecraft-seed)

Comment: Install minecraft 1.7.3 and make the world?